# Different ways to say numbers

Tags: numbers

I see in some videos diferent ways to say numbers, and I like learn this. If I say a telephon number for example, I can change "zero" for "o".

9090-3578

- nine zero nine zero tirty five seven eight
- nine o nine o tirty five seven eight

Today I see one video in youtube one pearson say for the year 1900 in the different ways:

- nineteen hundred
- one thousand nineteen hundred

I'm interesting in study different ways to say the numbers. Could you give examples of other more usual simplified forms of saying numbers?

Comment: 1900 is "one thousand, nine hundred".

Comment: How numbers are spoken and with what cadence depends on the kind of number and on the locale; there is a [Numberphile episode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YBbBbY4qvv4) that points out some differences in US and UK usage, for example. In some fields, like aviation or the military, the way numbers are spoken is highly prescripted. In no case is *1900* ever *one thousand nineteen hundred*, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you are speaking the number

> "five thousand and fifty two"

or you are reading the digits

> "five zero five two" or "five oh five two"

For telephone numbers, which are actually just strings of digits, you only use the second way. You may use either "zero", "oh" or (BrE) "nought" for 0. All three are correct. Sometimes double digits will be indicated, but this is not required.

Dates tend to use years over 1000: "nineteen twenty-four" for 1924. (For a few years after 2000 we say "year two thousand", probably due to a famous book called "2001" or "two thousand and one".)

Since 2010 we have increasingly gone back to saying "twenty ten" etc.